# How to add a partialFilterExpression to an index using reactiveMongo and play

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am trying to add an unique index to a field to a document where the collection has several different kinds of documents.  I would like to use a partialFilterExpression to filter out unwanted documents and only apply the index to the documents I want.  An example in mongo is:

```
db.users.createIndex(
  { reference: 1 },
  { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { reference: { $exists: true } } })
```

I want to do the same but using reactive mongo, so far in my code I have:

```
collection.indexesManager.ensure(Index(("username, IndexType.Ascending"),createdIndexName,background = true,unique = true))
```

ReactiveMongo's Index doesn't seem to have a way to add a partialFilterExpression?  Is there a way to add this in a raw format possibly?

Comment: Please add a [feature request](http://github.com/reactivemongo/reactivemongo/issue/)

Comment: So I guess that means it doesn't exist?  I was afraid of that...